# How to make a ListView inside of another ListView and when the nested ListView arrives at the edge, scroll the main scroll flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, flutter-layout

I have a `SingleChildScrollView` above all of my pages so that the user is able to scroll the whole page because the page is long...

But, one of my widgets is a `ListView.builder()` and when the user gets to it and scrolls it scrolls the `ListView.builder()` but the problem is when I get to the edge of the nested ListView I can't get back to my main scrolling... Meaning the whole page is useless and I can't scroll the main page anymore and when I do, the nested scroll view shows the blue material indicators that there's no scrolling anymore...

Here's my code

```dart
return SingleChildSrollView(
      child: Container(
                child: LatestPosts(), // See this below;
                height: 550.0,
              ),
```

`LatestPosts()`

```dart
return IncrementallyLoadingListView(
                hasMore: () => _hasMoreItems,
                itemCount: () => posts.length,
                loadMore: () async => await _loadMoreItems(),
                onLoadMore: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _pageNum++;
                    _loading = true;
                  });
                },
                onLoadMoreFinished: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _loading = false;
                  });
                },
                loadMoreOffsetFromBottom: 2,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if ((_loading ?? false) && index == posts.length - 1) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        latestPostsList(context, posts, index),
                        PostShimmer(),
                        PostShimmer(),
                        PostShimmer(),
                        PostShimmer(),
                        PostShimmer()
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return latestPostsList(context, posts, index);
                  }
                },
              );
```

`IncrementallyLoadingListView` is literally the same as `ListView.builder()`;

How can I achieve such a thing? I want the user to be able to scroll the whole page not just the nested `ListView.builder()`

Comment: `NestedScrollView` maybe? the docs say: *"A scrolling view inside of which can be nested other scrolling views, with their scroll positions being intrinsically linked."*

Comment: @pskink Should my app have Slivers to be able to use this widget? I'm very confused

Comment: whats wrong with slivers? you can also use `CustomScrollView` where one of the slivers is `SliverList`

Comment: @pskink Can you please, make a simple answer with code? I'm lost and burnt out :| Please.I would really appreciate it. Also, I have never worked with slivers before...